# Стилизация alert, confirm, prompt

Tags: javascript, css

#### Описание

У всех браузеров есть стандартные 3 методы, которые вызывают 3 стандартные окна:

- `window.alert()`
  [image]
- `window.confirm()`
  [image]
- `window.prompt()`
  [image]

С ними удобно работать, так как они **встроенные** и **поддерживаются везде**. Каждый браузер стилизует их под себя и иногда они не совместимы с дизайном сайта.

#### Вопрос

Если ли какие-нибудь псевдо-селекторы, аттрибуты или способ какой-нибудь изменить их внешний вид? Предпочтительно стандартные методы css.

#### Уточнение

Речь не идет о создании новой конструкции который можно стилизовать и который заменит эти 3 окна. Поэтому я в начале вопросе подчеркивал, что окна встроенные и поэтому с ними удобно работать.

Comment: Стилизовать встроенные диалоговые окна нельзя.

Comment: На сколько я знаю нет, никаких специфических селекторов нет. Это единый монолит. Разве что где-то в самой системе есть какой-то xml или около того. В самом браузере **на стороне клиента поменять в них ничего нельзя**

Comment: Печально. Не, я трогать системные xml файлы не хочу, так как, допустим на Windows у меня получилось, а на Mac все взлетит к ени-фени и теперь давай это исправляй.

Comment: Вы заметили что когда висит такой диалог, то весь остальной JavaScript не работает? Не работают таймеры, фоновые закачки, любые колбеки. Вам это нужно? Не нужно. Используйте оконную библиотеку с диалогами, которые не будут блокировать весь JavaScript на страничке.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy заметил. Думаю это не только нужно, это правильно. Так как код ждет ответ от пользователя - прочтет или нет, что он нажмет, что он напишет. Не знаю насколько правдив мое предположение, но эта функция мне и нравится во встроенных окнах диалога. :-)

Comment: Эта функция делает программирование простым. И усложняет жизнь пользователя. Решать вам. Когда я вижу стандартное окно - сразу думаю что разработчик любит себя больше чем пользователя. Но разработчик один, а пользователей - сто тысяч.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ваша фраза будет стоять [у меня в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/324730/eccs0103?tab=profile).